# .htaccess redirect - two URLs with similar paths

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

So here's what I have.

- www.website.com/foo (pretty URL to use on marketing pieces)
- www.website.com/foobar (URL that actually exists on site)

I can get www.website.com/foo working perfectly with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /foo [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/redirected/url-goes-here/   [L,R=301]
```

But that makes the www.website.com/foobar URL go there as well.

I'm sure this is a regex issue and I just don't know the correct symbol to get things working properly, but how can I make /foo redirect properly without effecting /foobar ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/redirected/url-goes-here/   [L,R=301]
```

`REQUEST_URI` will get rid of the extra request headers that `THE_REQUEST` has. Then you can match the beginning and end of the requested URL with `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `RewriteCond`. Just be specific with the `RewriteRule` pattern

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ http://www.website.com/redirected/url-goes-here/   [L,R]
```

See more about [regular expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.